# Subspace topology vs order topology in subspaces

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

For a space $X$ and a linear order $<$ on $X$, we can define a topology $\tau$ by the basic open sets $U_{a,b}=\{x\in X: a<x<b\}$. 
Now, let $A\subset X$. We can endow it with the subspace topology $\tau'$ in the usual way, by calling all $U\cap A$, where $U\in \tau$, open. 
Moreover, we can consider the restriction of the order $<$ to $A$, and endow $A$ with the topology of open intervals by $U_{c,b}=\{x\in A: c<x<b\}$ (call this topology $\tau''$).

My question is: do we have that $\tau'=\tau''$?

Comment: $X = \mathbb{R},\, A = (-\infty,0) \cup [1,+\infty)$

Comment: @DanielFischer How is the order topology in $A$ different from the inherited one from $\mathbb{R}$? I don't immediately see it, though it might be obvious...

Comment: A neighbourhood basis of $1$ in the order topology is $(-\varepsilon,0) \cup [1,1+\varepsilon)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, yes, thanks - just saw this from the answer below, too... Why didn't you post your comment as answer?

Comment: @sqtrat Not "iff", the subspace and order topologies coincide on $(-\infty,0] \cup [1,+\infty)$.

Comment: Yes, sorry you're right, I'll delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $A=[0,1]\cup (2,3]$, then $(\frac{1}{2},1] = (\frac{1}{2},2)\cap A$ and so it is open in the subspace topology. But it's not open in the order topology.

Comment: Yes it is. It is $U_{\frac{1}{2},2}=\{x\in A: \frac{1}{2}< x<2\}$...

Comment: I edited it, it's fixed now.